# Add php code to end of every html link

Tags: php, html

I have a query. I want to add a php code automatically to the end of every link on a page. For example, if I have 100 html links on a page for example:

`<a href="http://example.com/" class="example">`

and I wanted to automatically change this to:

`<a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $ref; ?> class="example">`

for every link on my page, how would I best implement it? Unfortunately, it is not an option to simply add the php code to every single link on my page. I've seen only one post related to this from Google that did not help.

Comment: This would be easier with javascript

Comment: you can use `<?=` instead of `<?php echo` to echo something outside of PHP

Comment: @DejaVu Bad idea to take a shortcut...

Comment: If you do not want to do this on the client side (with JavaScript as John suggested), I think the fastest way to achieve this would be a RegularExpression.

Comment: @LucM why is it a bad idea to replace `<?php echo` with `<?=` ?

Comment: @Dejavu As always, google helps you ;-)  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: @DejaVu because not everywhere supports short open tags and they are ugly.

Comment: @DejaVu why so? short tags are not enabled by default in php.ini and its discouraged to use them http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: If you are running on an apache server then take a look at its include module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html I often use it to append dynamic stuff to pages in a generic manner separate from the applications php logic.

Comment: @LucM I read the post and most of the comments but they are very conflicting alot of people say it shouldn't be used and alot don't use  another way. I personally had no problems (yet) using them, and i'm only suggesting what you could do inplace of.. it's not something that must be done.

Comment: @Spechal Most of them do support them right? And personally i like using `<?=` rather than writing the full `<?php echo` when i'm writing in html or something. But that's just a personal preference i guess.

Answer (score 1):

If the inserting of the PHP code is a one-time task, you could use a "replace text" function of your editor.
You could have it replace each occurrence of

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class
```

by

```
<a href="http://example.com/<?php ... ?>" class
```

For example, have a look at Geany: https://askubuntu.com/questions/302914/find-and-replace-text-in-multiple-files-using-geany

If you have to do this often or automatically, you could use, for example, the [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/en/preg_replace) functions of php to process your input HTML files.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I am not sure if there was a php function to alter every link within a page.. for example how <base target='_blank' /> can alter the target for every link. So are you saying, to your knowledge either manual entry or javascript are the only solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can help you doing this.

```
function renameLinks(){
    var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i =0;i<myList.length;i++){
        myList[i].setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/<?php echo $ref; ?>');
    }
}
```

Create a function which takes a URL as parameter and it will generate your link:

```
function createLink(url){
  var newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.href = 'url'+'<?php echo $ref; ?>';
  return newLink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/<a href="http:\/\/example\.com\/"/<a href="http:\/\/example\.com\/<\?php echo $ref; \?>"/g' *.php
```

Run this in terminal, it will replace all

```
<a href="http://example.com/"
```

with

```
<a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $ref; ?>"
```

in all the *.php files of current directory.

**Update:**

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g'
```

- `sed` = Stream editor comment
- `-i` = replace original file
- `s` = the substitute command
- `old` = a regular expression describing the word to replace
- `new` = the text to replace it with
- `g` = replace all occurrence
- `*.php` = wildcard file name

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

Since you have to modify all your code,

why not remove the hard-coding of `http://example.com/` ?

With vim, you could use

`%s/http:\/\/example.com\/<?php echo $domain . $ref;?>`

you need to define `$domain` or use a constant:

```
define("MYDOMAIN", "http://example.com/"); 
php echo MYDOMAIN . $ref;
```

Then the replace (s as substitution) in vim would be

`%s/http:\/\/example.com\/<?php echo MYDOMAIN . $ref;?>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I've had a good look at your solution. I am unsure as how to apply this fix to my site and I am not too familiar with python programming. If I had a few links link (http://sugs.com/newin), (http://sugs.com/old), (http://sub.sugs.com/) for example.. how could I echo the $ref to the end of each of these links?